# PowerShell tries to use a proxy even though I have none selected

Tags: powershell, proxy

When trying to run a script that tries to download something from the NuGet website, I get the following error:

```
Preparing to run build script...
Unable to find version '0.30.0' of package 'Cake'.
  C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\: Package 'Cake.0.30.0' is not found on source 'C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\'.
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Cake.0.30.0' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (
x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  The remote name could not be resolved: '[proxyname]'

An error occurred while restoring NuGet tools.
At C:\Users\user\Documents\location\build.ps1:168 char:9
+         Throw "An error occurred while restoring NuGet tools."
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (An error occurr...ng NuGet tools.:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : An error occurred while restoring NuGet tools.
```

Note that I've replaced the proxy name with [proxyname]. The reason this error is strange, is that I've set my Internet Options to detect automatically and not use a proxy. The proxy is only applicable for my work. Is there a way to stop PowerShell from trying to use the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Powershell does not use the settings specified in Internet Options (accesible via Internet Explorer). The proxy must be configured via netsh. 
To check the currently set proxy use:
`netsh winhttp show proxy`
To clear the proxy settings use:
`netsh winhttp reset proxy`
You can also import the settings for IE by typing:
`netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie`
Setting or resetting the proxy server requires admin rights on the local machine.

Comment: Interesting, a call to netsh winhttp show proxy gives the result "Direct access (no proxy server)". Yet, when I run the script it still tells me that it's trying to go through the proxy?

Comment: Could you check the file NuGet.Config in %appdata%\NuGet, especially for something like "http_proxy"? Otherwise maybe ask your company if they are pushing like any proxy settings for NuGet?

Comment: no proxy setting in NuGet config under AppData/Roaming. Really weird! Still getting "The remote name could not be resolved: '[proxy]'"

Comment: when a computer is configured to fetch proxy settings via pac file (usually that's what organization likes to do), then they do not show up under netsh. it's a bit painful. Registry is the right approach.